# Запрос в MySql не очень рандомно выбирает записи

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Помогите усовершенствовать данный запрос( он должен выбирать рандомно запись из таблицы, но почему-то это происходит не очень рандомно - в таблице из 2000 записей стабильно выбирает записи только до 200 записи)

```
SELECT user_id, ht_number, q_number
FROM ht_user_p2
JOIN questions2 
ON questions2.q2_id = ht_user_p2.q_id
WHERE questions2.q2_public=1 
AND ht_user_p2.user_ball IS NOT NULL 
AND user_id > FLOOR(1 + RAND() * (SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM ht_user_p2))
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: в таблице то ок, а что относительно джойна и фильров where ?

Comment: сам запрос-то внутри `floor` тоже выдает до 200?

Comment: не знаю насчёт ```floor```, как это узнать?

Comment: `select floor(...)` ?

Comment: LIMIT без ORDER BY? мсье знает толк в извращениях...

Comment: Akina, вы бы вместо таких подколов, реально помогли бы)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, не самый быстрый вариант, но самый читабельный:

```
SELECT user_id, ht_number, q_number
FROM ht_user_p2
JOIN questions2 
ON questions2.q2_id = ht_user_p2.q_id
WHERE questions2.q2_public=1 
AND ht_user_p2.user_ball IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```